# ipython autocomplete stopped working for attributes

Tags: ipython

In ipython (2.1.0), parts of autocomplete stopped working.  I don't know what changed.

For instance, if I have an object and I do

```
object.<tab>
```

it used to list the attributes of the object, and no longer does.

It will still autocomplete filesystem paths and magic function names.

Comment: 1.8.1? That was never a version of IPython. The current version is 3.1.

Comment: thanks!  I got that by doing 

__ version __ I'm not sure what that is actually giving me.

Comment: Ah, I bet you've used `%pylab`, and the `__version__` is being imported from numpy. You now say you're on 2.1 - can you try upgrading? I think I remember this bug (do you have a `$PYTHONSTARTUP` file?), and we fixed it some time ago.

Comment: yep.  I used ipython --pylab actually.  where would such a file be?

Comment: `$PYTHONSTARTUP` is an environment variable; you can see it by running `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` on Linux/Mac, or `echo %PYTHONSTARTUP%` on Windows. If it points to a file, that file is run when starting Python for interactive use.